# struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA not working

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-s2hibernate

I am using struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA in a demo strut2 project with Hibernate. I tried my best but can not make it work. I am using all the latest jars.

***Am I missing something?***

Please help

**ERROR LOG**

```
2012-09-14 02:06:50 - [  INFO - SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor:41 ] --> Full Hibernate Plugin Validation could not detect Hibernate Validator 3.x
2012-09-14 02:06:50 - [  INFO - SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor:46 ] --> Full Hibernate Plugin Validation using Hibernate Validator 4.x
```

**Library in my project**

[image]

**When I access page than get error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

    com.myapp.dao.CustomerDAOImpl.listCustomer(CustomerDAOImpl.java:26)
    com.myapp.web.CustomerAction.listCustomer(CustomerAction.java:47)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)......
```

**My CustomerDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.myapp.dao;

import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;
import com.myapp.model.Customer;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    @SessionTarget
    Session session;

    @TransactionTarget
    Transaction transaction;

    //add the customer
    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        session.save(customer);
    }

    //return all the customers in list
    public List<Customer> listCustomer() {
        return session.createQuery("from Customer").list();
    }
}
```

**EDITED *********************

```
 @SessionTarget
        Session session;

        @TransactionTarget
        Transaction transaction;
```

Problem is in the above code when Session and Transaction is injected. I am wondering that this might be problem of struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA not supporting

```
hibernate-release-4.1.6.Final
hibernate-validator-4.3.0.Final
```

because plugin site http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/ mentioned that only supported versions are

*This plugin is compatible with Hibernate Validator 3.1.0 and 4.0.2 (since 2.2 version)*.

**Is that the problem. Have anyone used this plugin with above mentioned versions?**

**One more question: Can we use this plugin in the production environment?**

Comment: This does not look related to Hibernate Validator.  It looks like your Injection mechanism simply is not working.  What are you using?  CDI ?  Check/debug your DI mechanism enable logging on that.  Ensure it is bootstrapping and annotation processing covers scanning this class.

Comment: @darryl-miles, Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question. Please read edited at the end.

Comment: and if you use hibernate 3.6.10+ a NPE should be easy to check with a debugging breaking in CustomerDAOImpl what is the value of 'session' and 'transaction' you say it _IS_ injected but the NPE says otherwise.  Split the statement into 2 'Query q = session.createQuery(...);  return q.list();' which line is the NPE now ?

Comment: my question is why you want this? why you exposing your DB layer to UI any specific benefits or anything you getting?

Comment: @umesh-awasthi, You are asking why I want to use struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA OR HibernateSessionInterceptor?

Comment: well i suggested you the plugin in other question, but IMO i will never prefer that approach and i tend to separate my layers by defining certain set of ModelObject and DTO's. i hope i m clear enough here

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to use Hibernate 3 for plugin.

Beacause in Hibernate 4 `DTDEntityResolver` class's package is changed which use by plugin. In Hibernate 3 this class is in `org.hibernate.util` package while in hibernate4 this class is in `org.hibernate.internal.xml.util` package.